# Using thunderbird for sending emails over command line

Tags: command-line, email, thunderbird

When I receive orders I handle them in an admin tool. When processed, I launch thunderbird with command line, so it opens up email windows with prefille subject, to, from, body and file attachment.

I use thunderbird because it gives me extra documenation, backup and ease that I can see and search order emails in my email program when I handle customer inquiries.

I am now trying to fully automate my order processing, so it will work when I am away at holiday etc. without having someone to handle orders for me.

--

I have two problems:

1)

Thunderbird always asks me if I want to swich to online mode. I usually prefer to be asked, but when used over commandline I would the switch to happen automatically.

2)

Currently I need to press the "Send" button myself. I would like the email sent automatically as well.

--

Is what I am hoping for impossible? I would prefer using thunderbird as my "hub" simply because I like having all my emails sent together.

Answer (score 1):

According to this Question at Mozilla support it is NOT possible.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1144493

If sending email via command line would be possible TB would become attractive for hackers to send spam mail.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any instructions a human can perform using a computer can be automated. Imagine running the following commands from a Linux terminal:

```
SUBJ="Re: Meeting invite"
DEST="First Last <first.last@host.com>"
BODY="Clean the spam after meeting!"
thunderbird -compose "subject='$SUBJ',to='$DEST',body=$BODY" &
```

Then, find the window ID by searching for a word in the subject line, such as:

```
WID=$(wmctrl -l | grep -i thunderbird | grep Write | grep invite | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

From there, you can use other tools to send keyboard commands to the window ID specified by `$WID`, including <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> to send a message. (You may have to disable those pesky confirmation dialogs.)